# Managed to unmanaged code - recursive call within method

Tags: c#, marshalling

I have a C# function that is called by unmanaged code (PowerBuilder). I have installed the NuGet package “UnmanagedExports” by Robert Giesecke.

```
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;

internal static class UnmanagedExports
    {
        [DllExport("ExpTest", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]  
        public static int ExpTest([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string ddMMyyyy)
        {
          int WeekNumber;
          . . .
          . . .
          return WeekNumber;
        }
```

This works mostly fine, but there is a situation where I have to make a recursive call, passing a new string:

```
WeekNumber = ExpTest(“new string”);
```

PowerBuilder now crashes in the call and I assume this is because ExpTest expects an unmanaged string. 
Is it possible to recursively call this method, like make “new string” unmanaged somehow?

Comment: Why not simply put the actual logic in a method that's not marshalled (`ExpTestInternal`), so that has no problem calling itself, or anything else? (Also, obviously, make sure you're not just getting a stack overflow by the recursion not bottoming out -- I'm skeptical the marshalling is actually the problem, although I don't know exactly how the package works.)

Comment: @Jeroen Thanks, I did what you suggested and moved the logic to separate method and now it works fine. How can I tag a comment as best answer?